# Maganto 2.2.7 product image loading and loading on product details page but it appears on the Homepage/Frontpage

Tags: product, image, magento2.2.7

[image]

Product images are shown on the Main Front Home page but when single product image clicked and land on the product details page, product image is not shown not appearing instead a gif is loaded. I can't figure this out. Since the folders permission seems to be OK, memory limit set right and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check browser console if it points any specific javascript error. Please check the recent changes made on the site.

Additionally, if you are on production, assuming you have made some recent changes which need to be compiled try recompiling using

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

followed by

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: In Browser Console I am getting JSON Parse error. JQMIGRATE: Logging is active jquery-migrate.js:21:2
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal

Comment: In some latest commits, there may be something which can't be parsed by JSON. You need to check the latest commits and maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse